# Python I can't replace my string values

Tags: python, string, random, indexing, replace

I'm programming in Visual Code Studio with Python3.

So my first function generates a DNA String and my second function should replace 1 of the pairs from that string with two different ones. What am I doing wrong here. (The error I get starts with wrong syntax.)

Thanks again for helping.

```
import random as rd


def generateVirus(length):
    a = [rd.choice(["AT", "GC","TA", "CG"])for i in range(length)]
    return ("".join(a))


def mutate(virus):
    virus = [v.replace(virus[int(rd.random()*(len(virus+1))), rd.choice([virus]for v in virus]
    return virus

a = generateVirus(4)
b = virus(a)
```

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio warn you that your brackets aren't balanced?

Comment: You're missing both `]` and `)` on the line beginning with `virus =`

Comment: What is `rd.choice([virus]for v in virus]` supposed to do?

Comment: hi thanks for the response, to pick a pair from that string to be replace the other pair

Comment: Why not just `rd.choice(virus)`?

Comment: I tried but the error im getting is that virus is not defined

Comment: That can't be, it's the argument to the function.

Comment: Fixed that. 
virus = virus.replace(virus[int(rd.random()*(len(virus+1)))],rd.choice([virus]))
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156693/discussion-between-zorange-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random as rd

dna = ["AT", "GC","TA", "CG"]
def generateVirus(length):
    a = [rd.choice(dna)for i in range(length)]
    return ("".join(a))

def mutate(virus):
    start = int(rd.random()*(len(virus)/2)) *2
    replacement = rd.choice(["AT", "GC","TA", "CG"])
    newvirus = virus[0:start] + replacement + virus[start+2:]
    return newvirus



a = generateVirus(4)
b = mutate(a)
print(a) 
print (b)
```

this works now

Answer (score 1):

This seems balanced:

```
def mutate(virus):
    virus = [v.replace(virus[int(rd.random()*(len(virus+1)))]), rd.choice([virus]for v in virus)]
    return virus
```

But you never define a `virus` function that you call with:

```
b = virus(a)
```

Comment: I suspect it was copied wrong, and the last line is actually `b = mutate(a)`

Comment: I concur, still, forewarning OP. `v` is never defined either, but one error at a time.

Comment: You were right toonarmyC. It had to be b = mutate(a)